# Emacs color theme for unrecognized file types

Tags: emacs, colors, color-scheme

I'm very happy with my emacs color themes for `.c`, `.py`, `.m` files, etc.  But is there a way to make unrecognized file types use a certain color theme, i.e. to default to a certain colortheme?

Answer (score 1):

Luckily emacs24 introduces custom themes without the external color package.

```
M-x customize-create-theme
```

see http://batsov.com/articles/2012/02/19/color-theming-in-emacs-reloaded/

Depending on your needs you can define a progmode which live in the emacs/lisp/progmode directory.

To set a global color-theme there is the variable `color-theme-is-global`.